# How to do addition or substraction of two dynamic check boxes values

Tags: android

I have dynamic check boxes which are having values like
check box 1 = $ 20
check box 2 = $ 10
if i click one check box then the value should reflect in a text view and if i select two check boxes then the value should be added to that text view or deselect the check box the value should be subtracted from that text view. 
This check box values are coming dynamically so i need to add/subtract those two values and show the total value in the text view.
How can i do that please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hear is Tested code for this and working fine..

**try this**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

CheckBox cb1, cb2;
TextView tv1;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.checkBox1) {
        if (isChecked) {
            count = count + Integer.parseInt(cb1.getText().toString());
        } else {
            if (count != 0) {
                count = count - Integer.parseInt(cb1.getText().toString());
            }
        }
        tv1.setText("" + count);
    }
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.checkBox2) {
        if (isChecked) {
            count = count + Integer.parseInt(cb2.getText().toString());
        } else {
            if (count != 0) {
                count = count - Integer.parseInt(cb2.getText().toString());
            }
        }
        tv1.setText("" + count);
    }
}
}
```

Good Luck..

Comment: Hi vrund but my check boxes are coming dynamically means from the web services

Comment: can you show me what kind of data you are getting from services?

Answer (score 0):

for check box we have one event listener as `OnCheckedChangeListener`

override this listener for both of your Checkboxes(e.g chkBox1, chkBox2), and

check

```
int value1,value2;
if(chkBox1.isChecked){
//store value of this checkbox into one variable  i.e.
value1 = value of chkBox1;
}else{
// reset value for this chkBox1 i.e
value1 = 0;
}

if(chkBox2.isChecked){
//store value of this checkbox into one variable  i.e.
value2 = value of chkBox2;
}else{
// reset value for this chkBox2 i.e
value2 = 0;
}
int sum = value1 + value2;
textView.setText(sum + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnCheckedChangeListeners to do your task

```
 chkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(eventListener);
 chkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(eventListener);

 CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener eventListener=new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId())
        {
            case R.id.chk1;
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    //do your first task
                    //set your textbox values
                }
                break;
            case R.id.chk2:
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    //do your second task
                    //set your second text values
                }
                break;
        }


    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if you dont have t0o many check box and iteration is fine than you can try following code.

    public void addUserType(ProObj obj)
        {
            final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getActivity());
            cb.setText(obj.getamount());
            cb.setTag(obj);
            layUsertype.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    layUsertype.addView(cb);
                }
            });

//any listener method

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                double sum = 0.0;
                int childcount = layUsertype.getChildCount();
                for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
                    View v = layUsertype.getChildAt(i);
                    if(v instanceof CheckBox)
                    {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v;
                        if(cb.isChecked())
                        {
                            if(cb.getTag() instanceof ProObj )
                            {
                                sum+=((UserTypesObj) cb.getTag()).getamount();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
//update logic
        });
    }
```